# mantaining same session across the new tabs

Tags: jsp, servlets

Hey guys I am building a simple web application on jsp and servlet comprised of login page and then welcome page after successful login. When I login successfully and open new tab in the browser and redirect to the same url it goes to login page again but I want is since I have already logged in with previous tab it should go to welcome page in all other tabs like facebook gmail etc does

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LoginModel model=(LoginModel)request.getAttribute("login");
        System.out.println(model);
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("login", model);

        if(model.getL_id()==7959 && model.getPwd().equals("xyz"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }   
        else
        {
            response.getWriter().println("login id or password invalid");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to check in your login page if the user is login by checking the session if the user has a session redirect to the home page else login .... add your login jsp page code in the question body please

Comment: so you say i need to use session.isNew. No I didn't used any session check in login it simply goes to login controller and check for the username and password

Comment: so you should to use session to ensure that user  signed in before

Comment: Ahmed is wrong. You're looking for polling/pushing.